# “Can't find starting number (in the name of file)” when trying to read frames from .mov video in opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, windows-10

When running the command
`cv.VideoCapture(path)`
(with cv being an opencv-python import)

I receive the following error:

```
OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: 
error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file):
res\Confetti_Loop.mov in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

I have tested it on 3 different computers (all Windows 10) (with same imports) and only one ran the following code with no errors.

```
"""Separate thread file to deal with videos."""

from queue import Empty

import cv2 as cv
import pygame

from Constants import LOCAL_IO


def get_video(path, size, queue, max_queue, aspect=0):
    """Get video and add to queue once properly formatted."""

    video = cv.VideoCapture(path)
    if aspect == 0:
        size = keep_aspect_ratio(video, *size)
    elif aspect == 1:
        size = cut(video, *size)
    else:
        size = (int(size[0]), int(size[1]))
    while True:
        try:
            get = queue.get(False)
        except Empty:
            pass
        else:
            if get[0] == LOCAL_IO["Stop"]:
                break

        ret, frame = video.read()
        if not ret:
            video.set(2, 0.0)
            ret, frame = video.read()

        frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = cv.resize(frame, size)
        frame = frame.swapaxes(0, 1)
        surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame)
        surface.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        max_queue.put((LOCAL_IO["Video"], surface))


def keep_aspect_ratio(vid, bx, by):
    """Scales image to fit into bx/by, this method will retain the original image's aspect ratio."""

    ix = vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    iy = vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

    if ix > iy:  # fit to width

        scale_factor = bx / float(ix)
        sy = scale_factor * iy
        if sy > by:
            scale_factor = by / float(iy)
            sx = scale_factor * ix
            sy = by
        else:
            sx = bx
    else:  # fit to height

        scale_factor = by / float(iy)
        sx = scale_factor * ix
        if sx > bx:
            scale_factor = bx / float(ix)
            sx = bx
            sy = scale_factor * iy
        else:
            sy = by

    return int(sx), int(sy)


def cut(vid, bx, by):
    """Scales image without changing aspect ratio but instead growing to at least the size of box bx/by."""

    ix = vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    iy = vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

    if bx / float(ix) > by / float(iy):  # fit to width

        scale_factor = bx / float(ix)
        sy = scale_factor * iy
        sx = bx

    else:  # fit to height

        scale_factor = by / float(iy)
        sx = scale_factor * ix
        sy = by

    return int(sx), int(sy)
```

Why is this happening?

Edit:

Seems to be a problem with the file I am trying to read as I re-downloaded the video from my github repo and it worked. The video file was uploaded using git lfs would this be a reason why it got corrupted during the first download of the whole repo?

Comment: Where is the following code ?

Comment: Sorry about that have now edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Olli-Pekka Heinis](https://github.com/skvark) on https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/284. He says:

> Only reason I can think of is that PyInstaller does not copy the
> FFmpeg dll during the packaging process.
>
> If you have a look at e.g. ...Python37\Lib\site-packages\cv2 folder,
> there is something like opencv_videoio_ffmpeg412_64.dll next to
> cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd.
>
> Does the opencv_videoio_ffmpeg412_64.dll file exist in the package
> which was created in PyInstaller? If not, add it to the spec file
> (binaries):
> https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#spec-file-operation

Comment: Checked the folder, the dll file is there. (also I am not using PyInstaller)

Comment: Is probably a dependency conflict between OpenCV and a backend video encoding library. Have you tried reinstalling OpenCV yet?

Comment: Tried reinstalling but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this error message may show up when the file is not found, e.g. in opencv 4.5.5

Comment: The file had somehow been corrupted, I got it working by redownloading the video.